# CodeIgniter form method ignored

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, get

I use form_open() to start my form which generates this HTML:

```
<form action="https://myurl/login" id="loginForm" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_tokenname" value="csrf_tokenvalue" />                                      
<input type="text" value="test value" id="testText" name="testText" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="loginBtn">Login</button>
</form>
```

Inside my Login.php controller, I am simply printing the request method (while I try to figure out what's wrong.)

```
print $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

The submit button changes my URL to //myurl/index.php/login (like I expect) and I see that index() prints my method, but it's always

```
GET
```

I have ZERO form validation setup, but I can't imagine that would be the problem. I specifically state method is post in the form, but nothing I've done can get the Controller to show me a POST method.

I have similar forms in another project that work fine. My .htaccess is set up properly to rewrite index.php urls. Could it be just form validation rules? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you access any form inputs using $this->input->post('')??

Comment: I cannot - it is empty. The request method is GET, so I don't suppose there would be any input->post() values available.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Exists Between Chair and Keyboard.

Frustrating to figure out, but here it is.
I use DreamHost as my host, and they allow me to change `https://www.myurl` to just `https://myurl` if I want, or to change `https://myurl` to `https://www.myurl` (basically, handle the "www" in front of the URL, regardless of what people [or Codeigniter] puts in as the address).

Well, I had told DreamHost to INCLUDE the www in front of all my urls, but I had CodeIgniter configured with the wrong base url. In application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://myurl';
```

So, I switched it to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.myurl';
```

And now it's showing a POST request method.  DANG frustrating because of my own lack of attention to the details.